# How to add a reference to a .Net Core 3.1 project from a .Net standard 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

I have two projects, one which has a target framework .Net Core 3.1 called Common, and another which has a target framework .Net standard 2.0 called XamApp. How do I add a reference in XamApp to Common? I keep getting the error:

`Project Common is not compatible with uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299)/win10-arm. Project Common supports: netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)`

I'm making a Xamarin.Forms app, so XamApp supports only .Net Standard 2.0. What target framework do I need to change Common to be?

Comment: As I remember, Xamarin can't use dotnet core. It uses mono insted.

Comment: @IvanKhorin would I have to change the Common target framework to .Net Standard 2.0 then?

Comment: Yes, the error says that UWP project is not compatible with .NET Core 3.1. It is needed to target Common project as .net standard 2.0

Comment: Hi, you could have a look at [Portable Class Libraries (PCL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/pcl?tabs=macos) it can be used in Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need features of 2.1, then yes, to netstandard2.0 :)

Comment: Thanks! I changed the Common project to .Net standard 2.0 and not the XamApp project can reference it and access the classes I want.